# Git submodule: git@github.com: Permission denied (publickey). fatal: Could not read from remote repository

Tags: python-3.x, django, windows, git, github

I have a problem with `git submodule update --init --remote`.
I receive errors: Permission denied and Failed to clone. But I added SSH keys to my github repository. I can pull, push, git clone.

I have all needed accesses.
I use OS Windows 10.
I changed in .gitmodules file `url=git@github.com:xxx`  to `url=https://github.com/xxx` , but not helped.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Git will try to clone the submodule using ssh and not https. If you haven't configured your ssh key this will fail. Either change the URL from `git@github.com` to `https://github.com` in the `.gitmodule` file else please follow the steps which might fix the problem.

1. Delete the folder of the submodule from your local.
2. Open gitBash and run the following commands.

   ```
   git submodule sync
   git submodule update --init
   ```

Comment: Thank you verry much! I have deleted .gitmodule and comands in git bush. It's woks!

Comment: It prompts me to enter the pass key and it still fails, the key is working 100% because I could pull the repo containing the submodule

Comment: The command alone did not work for me. First I had to edit `.gitmodules` (note the 's') in the repo root changing `git@github.com:` to `https://github.com/` (note the ':' to '/'. Then the commands synced and updated the submodules.